# Copy row data if status in column changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-apps, google-sheets-api

My function is supposed to check column 8 for one of the statuses although it doesn't seem to work.

It checks to make sure it is a "purchase sheet", and it checks to see whether or not that purchase exists on the "dashboard", but it is only supposed to copy the row if I edit the status in "column 8" to one of the following "yes", "no", "repeat" or "sold".

Where have I gone wrong?

```
function copyRow() {
    var purchasedColumn = 8; //- column A = 1, B = 2, etc...
    var targetRange = targetDashboardSheet.getRange(targetDashboardSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    if (purchaseSheet && range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn && ["Yes", "No", "Repeat", "Sold"].indexOf(range.getValue()) > -1 && taskDashboardRange === -1) {
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
    }
}
```

I don't believe this bit is working

```
range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn && ["Yes", "No", "Repeat", "Sold"].indexOf(range.getValue()) > -1
```

**Update**

I have realized that I have a separate function interfering with the copyRow function. So my code is actually working and then being overwritten with another crossUpdate function.

Thanks for the help, it's always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and look in the Log after running the debug.  You should see a list of row numbers and the value for rows with that cell matching the test.  I only tested for Yes and No.  I also limited my range to only the column you are checking against.  You could expand it to the entire row so you are set to copy that row.

```
function copyRow() {
  var targetDashboardSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var purchasedColumn = 8; //- column A = 1, B = 2, etc...
  var targetRange = targetDashboardSheet.getRange("H1:H");
  var values = targetRange.getValues();

  for (i in values) {
    if (values[i][0] === "Yes" || values[i][0] === "No") {
      Logger.log("row: " + i + " Value: " + values[i][0]);  
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I have realized that I have a separate function interfering with the copyRow function. So I cannot mark your answer as the "answer".